# How to cast protocol inherited to specified class?

Tags: ios, swift

I have

```
protocol BirdProtocol {
  var kukku
}


class Bird : BirdProtocol {
  var canFly
}
```

my view controller hold this one

```
var mypet : BirdProtocol
```

**problem :**

I can call `mypet.kukku`
I cant call `mypet.canFly`

I have tried casting mypet as? bird

but seem not working , anyway to cast protocol to class ? thanks

Comment: your protocol should have `canFly` or you just don't need a protocol

Comment: Your property's type is `BirdProtocol` and `BirdProtocol` does not have `canFly()` function. You can reach only property type's attributes.

Comment: Then what you are expecting ??,  BirdProtocol doesn't know what is `canFly` !!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you should consider if you need a protocol or if you need to add `canFly` to it. Basic casting works though

```
if let bird = mypet as? Bird {
    print(bird.canFly)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let newMypet =  as? Bird{
    print("kukku: ", newMypet.kukku, " CanFly : ", newMypet.canFly)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot cast a protocol to a class type as that class is a not a member of protocol . On the other side you can cast a class inheriting a protocol as your class  have that protocol conformance.

Comment: This is not true, you can cast a class from a protocol

Comment: Do you have any reference regarding that ??

Comment: A reference? Just try to cast a protocol to a class which conforms to that protocol and it succes... lol